# Cherry-pick from closed pull request without fork branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I got a pull request that contains two commits, one of which I'd be willing to merge.

However, the pull request has already been closed (not merged) and the corresponding branch deleted from the fork repo.

Is there a way to cherry-pick that commit? Or more generally, is there a way to merge a closed pull request without access to the fork branch?

Comment: PR is closed AND merged?

Comment: @ppasler No, just closed.

Comment: So the commit can nowhere be found?

Comment: @ppasler It's still in the GitHub pull request, but aside from that, no.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: As I see it, this can't be done and is only possible for open PRs: http://mispdev.blogspot.de/2013/02/github-cherry-picking-commits-from-pull.html. I would copy the wanted changes and commit them myself (I am sure you had this idea yourself).

Comment: @ppasler that's non-sense, you have all PRs as remote branches in the `pull` namespace

Comment: @Vampire oh cool, didn't know that. I thought it's getting deleted after the PR is closed. Sorry for misleading comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git fetch origin pull/36/head
git log FETCH_HEAD
```